# How to use both should and done in mocha and chai with node.js

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, chai

I'm just starting learning mocha and chai. And I get stuck here

```
const UserService = new Service();
describe("user-services.spec", () => {
    describe("Services testing", () => {

        before((done) => {
            db();
            userModel.remove({}, done);
        })

        after((done) => {
            mongoose.connection.close();
            done();
        })

        it("should add user to db", () => {
            let id = 4;
            let name = "Alen";
            (async () => {
                let result = await UserService.addUser(id, name);
                console.log("result", result);
                result.should.have.property("_i");
                //done();
            })();
        })
    })
})
```

Now I have two question based on above code

1. Is that this test case always pass even if I change "_id" to "_i" I don't know how ?
2. If I want to use done with above code and uncomment the done() then it gives error

> Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first question, I've tested using `result.should.have.property("_i");` and it fails.
I've mocked the method like this:

```js
async function addUser(id, name){
  return {_id:""}
}
```

And it throws

```
Uncaught AssertionError: expected { _id: '' } to have property '_i'
```

As expected.

So check the value returned. Also you can check chai [documentation](https://www.chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_property)

And for the second question, `done()` is the callback to say Mocha where the function is done. Also Mocha has a timeout (max. time the test will be waiting). If the maximum time is reached without a `done()` calling, Mocha will thrown an error saying it has not been finished (done is not called).

If you don't call `done()` Mocha will stuck waiting without knowing when the function is completed.
You get the error `Timeout of 2000ms exceeded` because  2 seconds is the default value as [documentation](https://mochajs.org/#-timeout-ms-t-ms) says.

> Specifies the test case timeout, defaulting to two (2) seconds (2000 milliseconds). Tests taking longer than this amount of time will be marked as failed.

Comment: but in my case it passed and with my second question it gives error even I use done() at the end see my above code if I uncomment the done()

Comment: Are you sure your code reach `result.should.have.property("_id");` or is tin `await` line? Also, post more context or try to using another function mocked and check if the function is returning data correctly.

Comment: I don't know that result.should.have.property("_id"); is executing or not but I use console.log(result) just before result.should.have.property("_id"); and It print result object properly and in console I see that every test case is passed. So what is the problem ?

Comment: I also tried by comment  result.should.have.property("_i") and in that case also it pass the test. So I think result.should.have.property("_id") is not executing. So now what's wrong with him ?